# What's the difference between the D and DTR parts?

Tags: integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply, driver, power-factor-correction

Is DTR just the same as D which is packaged in tape and reel? If  so, was it really necessary to categorize them like this?

[image]

Comment: D may be packed in ruler. Then you create the order for you SMT, it is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the L6562 datasheet, the table you have copied is for the **order codes.**  That's the part number you put in your order.  If you want the L6562D delivered on tape and reel, then you must order the L6562DTR rather than the L6562D which is not delivered on tape and reel.  The parts you receive will be marked "L6562D" rather than "L6562DTR," but they'll be delivered in tape and reel.

Yes, it makes sense to separate the **order** codes that way.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case the obvious is overlooked (I do so all the time!), the "TR" = **T**ape and **R**eel.

Some people have board assembly machines that accept components in tubes and some that accept them in tape and reels.

Comment: +1 for mentioning tubes.